# How do I store the value of a combobox into a variable?

Tags: perl, combobox, cgi

New to CGI and perl.

I am passing my CGI to a perl script with GET. I have a combobox and I want to store the value of the selection into a variable so that I can manipulate the value in my CGI script.

I want to take the selected number from the combo box and store it in a variable called 'dayslate' so that I can use the value for mathematical calculations.

```
<select name = "dayslate">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

The combobox code is in my perl file and I want to grab the value and store the value in my CGI script. I think this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

When the user submits this form, there will be a parameter in the format of:

```
dayslate=2
```

Where the number will be the value in the value attribute of the selected option.

On your back end, you can get the value of this parameter from the request.

```
 $dayslate = param('dayslate') || 'no dayslate param passed in';
```

Comment: Follow up question (if that's allowed, new to stackoverflow), I want to check to see which radio button is selected in a group.


`<input type = "radio" name = "type" value = "book"/>  Book
<input type = "radio" name = "type" value = "audiobook"/>   Audio Book`


In an if statement to check which is selected would I do:


`if (param(type) == 'book')
{
}
else #assume audiobook is selected
{
}`

Comment: Hi @AnnaDrewNewby yes, if one of the radio buttons is selected, it will be passed the exact same way. e.g. if you have `<input type="radio" name="color" value="red"/><input type="radio" name="color" value="blue"/><input type="radio" name="color" value="green"/>` you will have a param like `color=green` if that is what the user chose. (if the user doesn't pick any option, you won't see the param on the server)

Comment: Much appreciated!